# Git push failed after git rebase

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am new to Git and I am trying to understand what is the best practice to keep my code base update with the latest changes to the master branch.
Here is my situation - I am working on a feature, say feature A, and I create a branch from my master with the name featureA using `git checkout -b featureA`.

I understand that at this point, featureA is my local branch that is same as the local master branch (because that's where I have branched from). I add my changes to my local branch and at the end of the day, I commit my changes and push to my remote branch (origin/featureA).

Next day, I want to continue working on featureA from where I have left off. So I rebase my featureA branch with the latest master. For this I use,

```
git fetch
git rebase -i origin/master
```

Usually, this works fine. But again at the end of the second day, when I try to push my latest changes to my remote branch (origin/featureA), I cannot do so and I get the following message -

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I tried pushing my changes with `git push -f`, but even that didn't help.

However, if I merge the master branch into my feature branch (and not rebase of master branch), I can push to the remote feature branch.

Please help me understand -

Is rebase a good option when working in a large team? If yes, then how to avoid the situation above? If no, then what is the other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

When you rebases your local `featureA` branch, the history line of the branch changes. The history line of this local branch diverges with the repo "featureA" branch.

To push a diverged branch to its remote counterpart, you need to do a "force push" with `-f`, short for `--force`.

```sh
git push origin featureA -f
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are unable to push your local branch to a remote branch, it is most likely due to one of two reasons:

1. Somebody else has already pushed to the remote branch, causing your
   local branch to become out of sync and git to acknowledge merge
   conflicts
2. You have modified your local commit history in such a way
   that pushing would require changing the remote commit history

Option 2 is likely to happen if you use 'rebase' instead of 'merge'.  Typically, I would suggest avoiding rebase at all costs in favor of merge: rebase will literally alter your commit history (with the added benefit of keeping the commit tree somewhat clean), while merge will preserve commit history with the "downside" of making your commit history somewhat complicated.

The following process will always ensure a smooth git experience:

- branch from 'master' (or desired branch) with 'git checkout -b '
- develop locally then push your branch up to remote with 'git push --set-upstream origin  (assuming you're the only person working on this branch)
- periodically "rebase" with master (rebase here being a general term, the actual git command you use is 'merge') with 'git merge master' while checked out to your local branch

Example:

```
git clone <repo>
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout -b <branch_name>
... development
git add *
git commit -m "message"
git push --set-upstream origin <branch_name>
... development
git add *; git commit -m "message"
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout branch_name
git merge master
... resolve conflicts, if any
git push <branch_name>
... repeat until pull request
```